# No Underscores Allowed in Freeform Field Handles?

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace

We're trying to use Solspace Freeform with a third party CRM and it (the CRM) has a field name convention that uses underscores (x_firstName, etc). We're trying to set up corresponding forms in Freeform and want to map fields using the same field names as the CRM but it appears that it (Freeform) will not let you use underscores when typing out the handle for a field.

Does anyone have any knowledge of this? It seems an odd convention in Freeform to disallow underscore in its field handles.

Answer (score 2):

Not likely to be an issue for anyone in the future but just incase someone is looking at this... Turns out Freeform should be able to handle underscores in field handles. Just an oversight on the Solspace side and they're going to be patching in support for underscores shortly.